# Make hover into a click interaction on mobile devices only

Tags: html, css, reactjs, rxjs

I have some cards that turn around when hovering over them in this css file:

```
   .container:hover .front,
    .container:hover .back{
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
        transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
        -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
        transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
        transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    }
```

I already detect touch devices with this function:

```
  const touchDevice = "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement;
```

Is there a way to make it like an onClick function on those cards so they stay in their "hover" state when they are turned around ? Because as you may know hovering on mobile devices does not really work...

Answer (score 0):

try using onmousedown maybe that will work

Comment: where in the css ?